# Java. JNativeHook requires permission to run "this computer" every time it starts

Tags: java, permissions

Good day,

My issue is the following:

1. The nature of the App - virtual keyboard with optional design which can be saved to a setting file. Crated with IntelliJ_Idea.
2. The app uses JNativeHook to listen to NativeKeyListener.
3. An instance of GlobalKeyListener is created at the very beginning of the main class.
4. The app is packed into dmg bundle with javapackager.
5. After the app has been installed and given permission to run "this computer" for the first time (due to usage of JNativeHook) - everything works perfectly. But when ...
   6.The user makes any changes to the design of the keyboard.
   7.The app saves new parameters into a setting file belonging to the package content of the installed app in OS X.
6. Next time the user tries running the app - the app needs to be given permission to run "this computer" again. (JNativeHook throws an exception : Failed to enable access for assistive devices)
7. Permission granted via System Preferences agin.
8. Everything works fine until the next time the app changes the settings file.
9. JNativeHook throws the same exception again, permission needs to be granted anew.

PS. Essentially any changes to the package content (coping files, write to files) and JNativeHook needs to be granted permission anew in System Preferences in OS X.

Would appreciate any help.
Thank you.
Maxim.

Comment: The solution is to not put the user's settings into a file that is part of the package content.  Put them somewhere else.

Comment: Stephen C - thank you very much I just done and it worked!